# Триггер не видит название кнопки которая вложена в popupbox

Tags: c#, wpf

Триггер не видит название кнопки которая вложена в popupbox но если кнопку вынести за пределы popupbox то все работает. Как сделать чтобы триггер увидел имя кнопки которая лежит в pupupbox?

//Триггер - открытия и закрытия окна

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnOpenMaterial">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OpenMaterial}"/>
      </EventTrigger>
     <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnCloseMaterial">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CloseMaterial}"/>
     </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

//Popupbox в котором лежит кнопка

```
<materialDesign:PopupBox Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignMultiFloatingActionPopupBox}"
                                 PlacementMode="TopAndAlignCentres" 
                                 UnfurlOrientation="Vertical" 
                                 Margin="0 0 10 10" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                 Background="#FFF44336" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="sa" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Button Name="btnOpenMaterial" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniAccentButton}"                     
                    Width="40" Height="40" Padding="0" Background="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" >

                        <Button.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Placement="Left" Content="Материалы"/>
                        </Button.ToolTip>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </materialDesign:PopupBox>
```

Comment: Код текстом разместите. Скриншоты могут быть как дополнение, но не как основа!