# Триггер не видит название кнопки которая вложена в popupbox. Как сделать чтобы триггер увидел название кнопки?

Tags: c#, wpf

Триггер не видит название кнопки которая вложена в popupbox но если кнопку вынести за пределы popupbox то все работает. Как сделать чтобы триггер увидел имя кнопки которая лежит в pupupbox?

//Триггер - открытия и закрытия окна

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnOpenMaterial">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OpenMaterial}"/>
      </EventTrigger>
     <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnCloseMaterial">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CloseMaterial}"/>
     </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

//Popupbox в котором лежит кнопка

```
<materialDesign:PopupBox Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignMultiFloatingActionPopupBox}"
                                 PlacementMode="TopAndAlignCentres" 
                                 UnfurlOrientation="Vertical" 
                                 Margin="0 0 10 10" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                 Background="#FFF44336" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="sa" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Button Name="btnOpenMaterial" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniAccentButton}"                     
                    Width="40" Height="40" Padding="0" Background="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" >

                        <Button.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Placement="Left" Content="Материалы"/>
                        </Button.ToolTip>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </materialDesign:PopupBox>
```

Comment: И зачем [дублировать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1059425)?

Comment: Используйте `x:Reference` вместо `ElementName`. `ElementName` работает через поиск по визуальному дереву элемента с заданным именем. А у Popup содержимое рисуется в отдельном окне (да, Popup реализован, как прозрачное безрамочное окно поверх основного) и из-за этого его содержимое находится в совершенно другом визуальном дереве, поэтому триггер и не может найти этот элемент.

Comment: @John если использовать x:Reference вместо x:Name то пишет что не определено пространство имен. Как с этим быть?